# Как сделать смену активного пункта меню при скролле ?(jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка, menu

сразу к проблеме!
Есть меню на одностраничный сайт(*код ниже*).
Это меню изменяет активный пункт только при нажатии на сам пункт. (происходит плавная прокрутка к указанному месту).
Но если воспользоваться **колесиком мыши**, cмена активного пункта не произойдет.
Как сделать ,чтобы при прокрутке страницы **колесиком** изменялся активный пункт меню с помощью **js** или **jquery**?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
<style>
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 64%;
    margin-left: 18%;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
}
.header-conteiner{
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #828282;
    padding-top: 32px;
    padding-bottom: 33px;
}
.main-menu{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.main-menu .menu-link{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color:#828282;
}
.main-menu .menu-link.active{
    color: #070707;
}
.description{
    height: 420px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 88px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 104px;
}
.about{
    background: #F6F6F6;
    height: 900px;
    padding-top: 120px;
    text-align: center;
}
.title{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 34px;
    line-height: 42px;
    color: #070707;
}
.skills{
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 91px;
    height: 600px;
    text-align: center;
}
.portfolio{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
    height: 1200px;
    padding-top: 113px;
    text-align: center;
}

.contacts{
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 100px;
    height: 800px;
    text-align: center;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="header-conteiner">
          <div class="main-menu">
              <a class="menu-link active" href="javascript://0" onclick="slowScroll('#de')">Home</a>
              <a class="menu-link" href="javascript://0" onclick="slowScroll('#ab')">About me</a>
              <a class="menu-link" href="javascript://0" onclick="slowScroll('#sk')">Skills</a>
              <a class="menu-link" href="javascript://0" onclick="slowScroll('#po')">Portfolio</a>
              <a class="menu-link" href="javascript://0" onclick="slowScroll('#co')">Contacts</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section class="description" id="de">
        <h2 class="title">Home</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="about" id="ab">
        <h2 class="title">About me</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="skills" id="sk">
        <h2 class="title">Skills</h2>

    </section>
    <section class="portfolio" id="po">
        <h2 class="title">Portfolio</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="contacts" id="co">
        <h2 class="title">Contacts</h2>
    </section>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('click' , '.main-menu a', function(){
          $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        })

        function slowScroll(id) {
          var offset = 88;
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(id).offset().top - offset
          }, 500);
          return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, не использовать jQuery. Но если прям очень надо, то [jQuery Scrollfire](https://github.com/Xaxis/jquery.scrollfire).

Comment: не то , что мне нужно